# No option to go back?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10s

I had an old PC lying around. I installed Windows 10 S in it. Then I tested it and didn't liked it, So I decided to Go back to previous build. There are Windows.old folders but no option to go back. Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest me what to do?

You will have to reinstall whatever version of Windows you were using.  It will not be possible to revert back to your previous installation. **You were warned you were installing Windows over itself.** You will want to manually backup the files contained within Windows.old before you reinstall the version of Windows you actually want to use.

> I had an old PC lying around. I installed Windows 10 S in it. Then I tested it and didn't liked it, So I decided to Go back to previous build.

You cannot upgrade an existing installation of Windows to Windows 10 S Mode.  You actually performed a clean install, which mean, you cannot revert to your previous installation.

Comment: ok i will reinstall, thanks anyway

Comment: _You will want to manually backup the files contained within Windows.old before you reinstall the version of Windows you actually want to use._ not needed as there was no files.

Comment: @Jhon - You indicated that Windows.old existed.  You failed to make it clear none of your files were migrated to it. My advice is sound in general, might not apply to you specifically, but normally one would manually transfer the files contained within Windows.old

Comment: Sure Thanks for it, but its my spare PC which didn't contained any files at all! So i upgraded, i would not in my primary PC.

Answer (score 0):

If the option to go back has expired or (for whatever reason) was not there, then you need to back up any data and re-install your prior operating system.

Go back has limitations, so the absence of Go Back means re-installing Windows.

Comment: So its not possible now?

Comment: Yes correct it is not possible if the option expired or was not there